# Bind events on AngularJS element directives using jQuery

Tags: jquery, angularjs, events, angularjs-directive, jquery-events

I have a directive in AngularJS:

```
module = angular.module("demoApp", [], null);
module.directive('sample', function () {
    return {
        restrict: "E",
        transclude: true,
        replace: true,
        template: "<div ng-transclude></div>",
        controller: function ($scope, $element) {
            this.act = function (something) {
                //problematic line HERE
                $element.trigger("myEvent.sample", [something]);
            };
        }
    };
})
.directive('item', function () {
    return {
        restrict: "E",
        require: "^sample",
        transclude: true,
        replace: true,
        template: "<a ng-transclude style='display: inline-block; border: 1px solid crimson; margin: 2px; padding: 5px; color: crimson; text-decoration: none; background: #f5d0d0; cursor: pointer;'></a>",
        link: function (scope, element, attributes, parentController) {
            element.on("click", function () {
                parentController.act(this.innerText);
            });
        }
    }
});
```

And in my HTML I use it thus:

```
<sample id="myElement">
    <item>1</item>
    <item>2</item>
</sample>
```

Which will be rendered as:

```
<div ng-transclude="" id="myElement">
    <a ng-transclude="" style="display: inline-block; border: 1px solid crimson; margin: 2px; padding: 5px; color: crimson; text-decoration: none; background: #f5d0d0; cursor: pointer;;display: inline-block; border: 1px solid crimson; margin: 2px; padding: 5px; color: crimson; text-decoration: none; background: #f5d0d0; cursor: pointer;" class="ng-scope"><span class="ng-scope">1</span></a>
    <a ng-transclude="" style="display: inline-block; border: 1px solid crimson; margin: 2px; padding: 5px; color: crimson; text-decoration: none; background: #f5d0d0; cursor: pointer;;display: inline-block; border: 1px solid crimson; margin: 2px; padding: 5px; color: crimson; text-decoration: none; background: #f5d0d0; cursor: pointer;" class="ng-scope"><span class="ng-scope">2</span></a>
</div>
```

I want to be able to listen to events triggered manually through jQuery:

```
$("#myElement").on("myEvent.sample", function (e, something) {
    alert("click: " + something);
});
```

I want this event to be triggered whenever the link is clicked.

If I set the `replace` property to `false` on the `sample` directive, it works. I guess it is because at the point where the event is fired, the element `sample` no longer exists, and as such it will have been replaced by the inner template.

So, how do I accomplish this?

Doing this, as suggested in the answer below, will not accomplish my purpose:

```
$($element).trigger("myEvent.sample", [something]);
```

Comment: link: function($scope, $element){ $element.click(function(){alert('clicked'):});}

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Please find below the fiddle

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sb_satchitanand/h49nz/)

Trigger is a jquery function which will work on proper handler.

```
$(element).trigger("myEvent.sample");
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you very much for your efforts. For that, you will get the accept. The actual problem was in the version of jQuery I was using. I was on 2.x. Seeing your fiddle steered me in the right direction.

Comment: @MiladNaseri I'm not sure, if I have read you right. I have updated my fiddle with Jquery 2.x and it is working as expected.[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sb_satchitanand/h49nz/1/). Did you mean was there any other issue because of the Jquery 2.x ?

Comment: Actually yes. I was just going over the AngularJS documentation and it specifically said that at 1.2.x they still do not support jQuery 2.x's event binding.

Answer (score 4):

Here's updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3u3zh/1/

There are several points worth noticing:

1. Because of the way angular transforms DOM, I would advice attaching all your custom listeners on body and then filter them by event target. `$('body').on('myEvent.sample', 'target-selector-expr', handler)` does exactly that. For example, if you use custom event listeners on `ngRepeat`ed elements, your handlers would not be executed because those elements would not exist at the time of trying to attach events to them.
2. It seems that angular's jqLite implementation is somewhat lacking in features when triggering events. Therefore I wrapped `sample`'s element in jQuery (`$($element)`) because otherwise the additional data would not get to the handler.

Final template:

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
  <sample id="myElement"><item>1</item><item>2</item></sample>
</div>
```

Js:

```
var myApp=angular.module('myApp',[]);
myApp.directive('sample', function () {
    return {
        restrict: "E",
        replace: true,
        transclude: true,
        template: "<div ng-transclude></div>",
        controller: function ($scope, $element) {
            this.act = function (something) {
               $($element).trigger("myEvent.sample", [something]);
            };
        }
    };
})
.directive('item', function () {
    return {
        restrict: "E",
        require: "^sample",
        transclude: true,
        template: "<a ng-transclude></a>",
        link: function (scope, element, attributes, parentController) {
            element.on("click", function(e) {
                parentController.act(this.innerHTML);
            });
        }
    }
})

$(document).ready(function(){
    $("body").on("myEvent.sample", '#myElement', function (e, something) {
        alert('clicked: ' + something);
    });
});
```